# Xamarin Forms: iOS Linking Framework

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, .net-core

I have an app that is ready to be sent to Apple so they can review it. Everything works fine except that when I send it to App Store Connect I get an email saying that it is too large.

After doing some research I found, that pretty much the last resort, is to change the linker behavior. I had it set to Don't Link and everything worked just fine, except having too big of a file at about 68.4 MB. When I changed Link Framework SDKs Only, the app runs, but I cannot get past my login because I get an error though it does connect to the database.

This is the error I get:

```
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.SqlServerCompositeMethodCallTranslator' threw an exception.
```

Here is the Inner Exception:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
```

Here is the stack trace, if you can use it at all:

```
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x00065] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0000d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00072] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0000d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00072] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0000d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00072] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0000d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00072] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0000d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00072] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00080] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00080] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00080] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00080] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00080] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00080] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00080] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00080] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0001b] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00056] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0002d] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00080] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite callSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x00000] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0 (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) [0x0003e] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService (System.Type serviceType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) [0x00032] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService (System.Type serviceType) [0x00013] in <286bee37a82942dd9a9ac759189d96e2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService (System.IServiceProvider provider, System.Type serviceType) [0x00034] in <e923201aa4e848f9b00b0bc074d511ff>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T] (System.IServiceProvider provider) [0x0000e] in <e923201aa4e848f9b00b0bc074d511ff>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies () [0x00008] in D:\Visual Studio Programs\Training\Class Library\EntityFrameworkCore-release-2.2\EntityFrameworkCore-release-2.2\src\EFCore\DbContext.cs:330 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider () [0x000dd] in D:\Visual Studio Programs\Training\Class Library\EntityFrameworkCore-release-2.2\EntityFrameworkCore-release-2.2\src\EFCore\DbContext.cs:312 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies () [0x00008] in D:\Visual Studio Programs\Training\Class Library\EntityFrameworkCore-release-2.2\EntityFrameworkCore-release-2.2\src\EFCore\DbContext.cs:330 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model () [0x00000] in D:\Visual Studio Programs\Training\Class Library\EntityFrameworkCore-release-2.2\EntityFrameworkCore-release-2.2\src\EFCore\DbContext.cs:138 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[TEntity].get_EntityType () [0x0001b] in <e87c0bc6b254447dbdf8d9b8988dec1b>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[TEntity].CheckState () [0x00001] in <e87c0bc6b254447dbdf8d9b8988dec1b>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[TEntity].get_EntityQueryable () [0x00001] in <e87c0bc6b254447dbdf8d9b8988dec1b>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[TEntity].System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider () [0x00000] in <e87c0bc6b254447dbdf8d9b8988dec1b>:0 
  at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource] (System.Linq.IQueryable`1[T] source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate] predicate) [0x0001c] in <4aed07645cc84858a0e66663540f2bae>:0 
  at PDDataNetStandard.Repositories.UserRepository.GetByInstallUserNameAndPassword (System.String username, System.String password) [0x00015] in D:\Visual Studio Programs\PDPublished\PDDataNetStandard\PDDataNetStandard\PDDataNetStandard\PDDataNetStandard\Repositories\Repository.cs:87 
  at PDInstall.Views.LoginPage.LoginPDInstall () [0x00041] in D:\Visual Studio Programs\PDPublished\PDInstall\Main\PDInstall\PDInstall\PDInstall\Views\LoginPage.xaml.cs:62
```

How can I get my app to work?

**EDIT**

I put the linkskip in, but it doesn't seem to do anything, unless I am doing it wrong?

```
--linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.SqlServerCompositeMethodCallTranslator
```

Comment: You can tell the linker to skip that assembly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=vsmac#skipping-assemblies

Comment: Following with Andrew suggestion, an issue was opened for EF about this problem and they came with a Workaound to prevent the linker to strip out part of the library. The issue can be seen here (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10963#issuecomment-375837164) and a Sample app they created can be downloaded here (https://github.com/cwrea/XamarinTodo/)

Comment: Thank you both for responding, unfortunately neither of those things worked, unless I didn't add the LinkDescription or the linkskip correctly. As far as I know the LinkDescription is just a file that could be created and put in my solution, unless there is something else I need to do.

Comment: Never Mind! I just added System.Core and mscorlib to linkskip and it worked! Thank You Both!

Comment: Glad it worked. Please feel free to answer your question with the details of what you did to solve the problem so anybody else searching for the same problem can easily find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Andrew and @apineda for helping me solve this question.

I ended up just adding two things to my mtouch arguments

```
--linkskip=System.Core --linkskip=mscorlib
```

This worked no problem!